# Faster function than exif_imagetype()

Tags: php, image-processing

Can anyone suggest me faster function than `exif_imagetype()` or any code that can check if the remote image exists or not. The checking is done in loop.

Thanks

Comment: if it _exists_ or not? Assuming by remote you mean over HTTP, do an HTTP HEAD request - will either return 404 or 200. If it's a 200, you'll also get the `Content-Type` the server thinks the image is eg `image/jpeg` (assuming the remote server is set up correctly). That said, you need to provide code for us to have a reasonable chance of  helping you

Comment: Hi yes my request is over http facebook cdn profile image and my code is <img class="img-polaroid" src="<?=(@exif_imagetype($row['pic']))?$row['pic']:'pub/img/friend.png';?>">

Comment: Executing any function with a URL to retrieve the data will always be slow and is generally considered a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are just checking for the existence , so why not use implement a `file_get_contents` with a `timeout` ?

```
$contextStream = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'timeout' => 3,//That would be 3 secs
         )
));
echo file_get_contents('http://someurl.com/remoteimage.jpg', false, $contextStream);
```

Comment: On 48 loop iteration exif_imagetype() is taking 15 - 20 secs. But I am looking out for much faster then that. Will check your code might be faster. Thanks

Comment: Yeah you can adjust the `timeout` I have set there according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
$Headers = get_headers($url);

if(strpos($Header[0], '200')) {
    //Exists
} else {
    //Doesn't Exist
}
```

The first row of the response should be the http response message eg `HTTP/1.1 200 Ok`. Note that depending on the server and url, you could get any of the [Http Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). It's up to you to decide which ones count as success (eg if you get a 503 "temporarily unavailable", do you make a list and try later or just give up?)

That way you won't download the file just read the headers.

If it *does* exist you should be able to examine headers for the one containing `Content-Type` to get the image format